# Is there way to fix save files?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

I used Cheat Engine while playing game now the games keeps crushing after checking downloadable content. What should I do? I don't want to play from the start as I'm now lvl 53.

Comment: What did you do to your save? And why didn't you back it up beforehand?

Comment: I didn't know it will crush.

Comment: and i saved the save files, so can anyone help me ?

Comment: Answers from credible and/or official sources won't advocate cheating. You can always reverse changes in cheatengine as it's just an editor

Comment: How to reverse change in cheat engine?

Comment: Anyone gonna help ? Anyone ?

Comment: This is why you should always back up your save games before touching it. I'm afraid there is nothing you can do, I'm sorry for you man.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Steam to play, the save file should be in "\Steam\userdata\ **YourUserID** \351970\remote". The save file should end with the extension *.to12sav. Make a copy of this file(s) and save it in a safe place. Uninstall and then reinstall the game and see if this fixes your issue.

Please let me know if you are not playing on Steam and I can try to figure out the location of the save file.

Comment: no i dont use steam to play.

Comment: @swswsws I see in a comment above that you found your save files. You can also try backing up your configuration files which should be in "AppData\Local\BANDAI NAMCO Games\Tales of Zestiria\". After uninstalling, try copying back the save file after re-installation. I'm assuming Cheat Engine modifies configuration files, so your freshly installed game should be fine. You could always try copying back your old configuration files to see if the game still works with them. If not, re-do the process.

Comment: Few days ago I deleted save files then the game stars but after i put my back up save files the game doesnt works anymore

Comment: @swswsws and you've completely uninstalled the game, correct?

Comment: yeah i did uninstalled the game

Comment: @swswsws unless you've modified the save file, I'm not sure why the save wouldn't work on the freshly installed game.

Comment: @swswsws: "no i dont use steam to play." The game isn't available outside of Steam, where did you get the game: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Tales_of_Zestiria#Availability